# Rewiring a street side light which is operated via an inside switch and underground cable

Tags: light-fixture, rewire

With what wiring & conduit combination should I use to re wire a street side light (ca.40' from the house) currently with buried conductor and indoor switch. I would also like to add a outdoor GFCI outlet on the light pole.

Comment: Does this light work now?

Comment: Can you get us pictures (without disassembling any wiring!) of the inside of the switch and the connections inside the light? Additionally, a pic of where on the pole you want the receptacles to go and your thoughts on how you're attaching the box and getting the wires to that spot.

Answer (score 1):

Using the term "GFCI" indicates you are in North America. If you replace the wiring without conduit, it must be a minimum of 24 inches deep, with conduit used to rise above that depth into the lamp post / receptacle box. If you don't want to dig a trench that deep, you can use PVC conduit at 18 inches deep, or galvanized rigid or IMC steel conduit at 6 inches deep.

There are other conditional issues and options as well. If you are in the US, find a copy of the National Electric Code, Table 300.5, which lists all of the options. If you are in Canada there is a similar set of rules in the CEC, I just don't know the reference.

If you just use the same circuit for the receptacle and light, the receptacle will only work when the light is on. If you want it separate, use a 3 conductor wire, i.e. 2 hots, neutral and ground. Switch one of the Hots for the light, leave the other one to the receptacle hot all of the time.